# Why won't UNION work within CTE or subquery?

Tags: sql, union, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm trying to run a query via System i Navigator that selects from the combined result of a union.

This works fine:

```
SELECT AF15VC FROM DB.AF
UNION
SELECT AF15VC FROM BATCH.AFM
```

So why doesn't this work?

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT AF15VC FROM DB.AF
    UNION
    SELECT AF15VC FROM BATCH.AFM
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

And why doesn't this work?

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT AF15VC FROM DB.AF
     UNION
     SELECT AF15VC FROM BATCH.AFM
    ) AS AF
```

In both cases, I get this error:

> SQL State: 42601
>
> Vendor Code: -199
>
> Message: [SQL0199]
>
> Keyword UNION
>   not expected. Valid tokens: ). Cause . . . . . :   The keyword UNION
>   was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword UNION. 
>   The partial list of valid tokens is ). This list assumes that the
>   statement is correct up to the unexpected keyword.  The error may be
>   earlier in the statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be
>   valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Examine the SQL statement
>   in the area of the specified keyword.  A colon or SQL delimiter may be
>   missing. SQL requires reserved words to be delimited when they are
>   used as a name. Correct the SQL statement and try the request again.

I tried `UNION ALL` as well with no change in the result.

**Update:**

Since people keep thinking I'm not showing the actual queries, I added screenshots.  Here is the first query working fine and the second two failing:

[image: query 1]
[image: query 2]
[image: query 3]

Comment: Have you tried adding `;`?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda yes.  I also tried removing `AS` and `AS AF`.

Comment: Ok, but is this single statement or part of script/stored procedure?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda single statement

Comment: Interesting, both of these syntaxes work for me. I am at v7.2, what release are you on?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy 7.1

Comment: Are you showing the whole query, or a stripped down version that you didn't actually run? Both queries that you showed should work. One thing you might want to consider (for performance only) is `UNION ALL`. But, see my comments to Charles below.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy The intended query is more complex, but I actually can't get either of the trivial queries shown in my post to run either.  I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: Please show us the exact query that fails (you can rename tables and columns if you are not allowed to publish the original but do show us the whole query, not a stripped version).

Comment: @yper-crazyhat-cubeᵀᴹ The queries in my question are the exact queries that are failing.  I added screenshots to clear up the confusion.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy The queries in my question are the exact queries that are failing.  I added screenshots to clear up the confusion.

Comment: All three forms work on my AS400 run locally and remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently the system is actually version 5.1, not 7.1 as I had stated in a comment.  I mistook my version of System i Navigator for the database engine version (or OS, or whatever it is).  As far as I know, the really old version is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on release 7.2

```
with cte as (
select pmco#, pmmanf
from dtdata.pdpmast
union 
select pmco#, pmmanf
from devqdata.pdpmast
)
select * from cte;
```

**Note:** use `UNION ALL` if you don't have or don't care about duplicates.  `UNION` gets rid of duplicates and if there aren't any means a lot of wasted processing.

Comment: The real query is more complex.  I'm trying to do a query where the source is 4 tables that are identical in structure but contain data from different time periods.  Someone before me achieved this by doing this: {query on table 1} union {identical query on table 2} etc...  To eliminate the 3 copied-and-pasted queries, I'd rather do this instead if possible: query on {table 1 union table2 etc...}.

Comment: While it is correct that a `fullselect` is a combination of `subselects`, the `table-clause` (at least at v7.1 and later, and I believe much earlier). can contain a `nested table expression` which looks like `[LATERAL] ( fullsellect ) [correlation-clause]`.

Comment: I was able to look at a v5r3 manual, and even there the CTE syntax is `table-identifier [(column-name, ...)] AS ( fullselect [order-by-clause] [fetch-clause] )`. The nested-table-expression is similar except in the docs at v7.1 and earlier, the correlation-clause is a required component. And by test, at v7.2, the correlation-clause is still required. It could have been made optional at some later TR in v7.2.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy is correct, just tried it on 7.2 and it works fine.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your statements should work fine. Here is a test from my IBM i at v7.2, but it should work the same at v7.1, or at least all the way back to v5r3 based on the documentation that I can find.

```
create table tablea
  (field1    Char(10),
   field2    Char(10));
create table tableb
  (field1    Char(10),
   field2    Char(10));
insert into tablea
  values ('row1', 'mama'),
         ('row2', 'papa');
insert into tableb
  values ('rowa', 'timmy'),
         ('rowb', 'sissy');
```

then

```
select * from tablea
union
select * from tableb;
```

gives:

```
FIELD1      FIELD2      
------------------------
row1        mama        
rowb        sissy       
row2        papa        
rowa        timmy
```

and

```
with cte as (
  select * from tablea
  union
  select * from tableb)
select * from cte;
```

gives

```
FIELD1      FIELD2      
------------------------
rowb        sissy       
row1        mama        
row2        papa        
rowa        timmy
```

and

```
select * 
from (
  select * from tablea
  union
  select * from tableb) a
```

gives

```
FIELD1      FIELD2      
------------------------
rowb        sissy       
row1        mama        
row2        papa        
rowa        timmy
```